# Adding a Log4j logging to a Vaadin 8 application

Tags: java, vaadin, vaadin8

I've tried to follow a documentation here [Piping to Log4j using SLF4J](https://vaadin.com/docs/v8/framework/advanced/advanced-logging.html#advanced.logging.slf4j), but still can't get a correct adapter used. So, how could one use a`Log4j` in Vaadin 8 application?  What are the dependencies to be added to `pom.xml`?

Answer (score 3):

There are multiple additions/changes required to get logging working.

1. Along the dependencies mentioned in the documentation to be added:

   - SLF4J
   - jul-to-slf4j
   - slf4j-log4j12-x.x.x.j

A `log4j-core` should be added as well. The relevant snippet of pom.xml looks like this:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.8.1</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
   <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.29</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>jul-to-slf4j</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.29</version>
</dependency>
```

2. The next step is to add a `log4j.properties` file (in my case under `src/main/resources/log4j.properties`). Here you can configure your logging properties
3. As mentioned in the documentation, a `SLF4JBridgeHandler` should be added to a Servlet definition (in case, there is only one servlet)

```java
 @WebServlet(urlPatterns = "/*", name = "MyUIServlet", asyncSupported = true)
    @VaadinServletConfiguration(ui = MyUI.class, productionMode = false)
    public static class MyUIServlet extends VaadinServlet {
        static {
            SLF4JBridgeHandler.install();
        }
    }
```

4. Imports used for `Logger` and `LoggerFactory` are:

```java
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.slf4j.bridge.SLF4JBridgeHandler;
```

5. To verify a correct implementation is picked for a logger its simple name is printed `System.out.println("Adapter name:" + logger.getClass().getSimpleName());`. Output should be : `Log4jLoggerAdapter`

Note: I've used a `log4-core` less than `2.9` since I am using Java 8 and jetty [Error scanning entry ...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46878035/error-scanning-entry-meta-inf-versions-9-org-apache-logging-log4j-util-stackloca). You should upgrade to a newer version if your jre is > 8